# Point directoryIndex to multiple strings

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have home.php as a directory index file.
This can be accessed like: `http://localhost/joacmedia/home.php`

How do I make the server point to the same `home.php` if user type `http://localhost/joacmedia/index.php`

.htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex home.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rewrite the `index.php` to `home.php`

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ home.php [L]
```

Your htaccess should look like the following with these settings

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex home.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index.php$ home.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I believe it should be `RewriteRule ^index.php$ home.php [L]`

Comment: @anubhava  the file is in a subfolder, oops..  I didn't notice that. Updated the code just now. Thanks :)

Comment: If i copy the code the add it to my .htaccess. i get not found. How do I make it work with this line: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]  because am loading page controllers based on keyword from url variable

Comment: @jamesOduro did you place the code in htaccess in `joacmedia` folder?

Comment: yes please joacmedia is the site main directory and the .htaccess is in it..not in subfolder

Comment: @jamesOduro Please try the updated htaccess. If are still having any issues with this then  you can ask me I will help you sort this out.

Comment: @jamesOduro your welcome. Glad it worked . Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Keep your htaccess file besides `joacmedia` folder and try following rules.
Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^joacmedia/index\.php home.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: @jamesOduro, could you please do mention sample/example url which you are hitting and its not working? Thank you.

Comment: Your solution might work but remember being on the development side and your solution might not work when I upload it to the remote server (production server) ...because Joacmedia as the site directory will change

Comment: @jamesOduro, oh ok, in that case Amit's solution is best then, cheers and happy learning.